# Push notification for android ,Php, MySql don't work

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

hi everybody I'm trying to build a new push notification app, i follow a tutorial , so I've :
1- Mysql database on Myphp server
2- php project using Netbeans
3- Android application using googleplay liberary and GCM using eclipse

I don't know if I should do something rather than run the application on the emulator , as should I run the php project ???

Please anybody help me as when I run it on the emulator I got it crashed and get those errors

[my locat errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er4qM.jpg)

```
private boolean isGoogelPlayInstalled() {
   GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
   int resultCode = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
  if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

      if (api.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)){

          api.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);

     } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
              "Google Play Service is not installed",
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
     }
     return false;
  }
  return true;
```

}

Comment: Please do not post errors as images, especially cropped ones. Always link to the tutorial you're using. And if you can't get things working based on a tutorial and don't know what to do, get a better tutorial.

Comment: post your code and MainActivity line 92....

Comment: @helldawg13I edit the post ... you can find the line 92 is the second thine on my posted code

Answer (score 0):

Use Google API as emulator system image and add a Google Account to the emulator.

Comment: I do that but same thing crashed